# how to terminate rest request gracefully

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I want to terminate rest request coming to server without further processing if input params are missing.

Currently this is the implementation, which I think is not very good for **verify_required_params().**

I want to terminate this request without returning any value from **verify_required_params()** in case of missing params. else flow should continue.

Running this on flask server and open to include any new package for best/ optimized approach.

Can please someone suggest an optimize way for this?

```
@app.route('/is_registered', methods=['POST'])
def is_registered():
    _json = request.get_json()
    keys = _json.keys()
    customer = Customer()

    if verify_required_params(['mobile'], keys) is True:
        _mobile = _json['mobile']

        validated = validate_mobile(_mobile)
        registered = customer.find(_mobile)

        if not validated:
            response = get_response('MOBILE_NUMBER_NOT_VALID')
            return jsonify(response)

        if not registered:
            response = get_response('MOBILE_NUMBER_NOT_REGISTERED')
            return jsonify(response)

        response = get_response('MOBILE_NUMBER_REGISTERED')
        return jsonify(response)

    else:
        return verify_required_params(['mobile'], keys)
        


def verify_required_params(required, received):
    required = set(required)
    received = set(received)
    missing = list(sorted(required - received))

    data = {"missing_key(s)": missing}

    # response = app.response_class(
    #     response=json.dumps(data),
    #     status=200,
    #     mimetype='application/json'
    # )

    if missing:
        return jsonify(data)
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

[*You say it works in a RESTful way, then your errors come back as 200 OK*](https://youtu.be/nSKp2StlS6s)

In REST, your URL should encode all the information about your entity. In your case, you are identifying a client by their phone number, and you are getting rather than updating information about them, so your endpoint should look like `GET /client/<phonenumber>/registered`. That way, a request can't not provide this information without going to a different endpoint.

In short, your code will be replaced with:

```py
@app.route('/client/<mobile>/registered', methods=['GET'])
def is_registered(mobile):
    if not mobile.is_decimal():
        return jsonify({'error': 'mobile is not number'}), 400  # Bad Request
    customer = Customer()
    registered = bool(customer.find(mobile))
    # does it make sense to have a customer who is not registered yet?
    # if not, use:
    if not registered:
        return jsonify({'error': 'client not found'}), 404  # Not Found

    validated = validate_mobile(mobile)
    return jsonify( {'validated': validated, 'registered': registered} )
```

In addition, it's better to have the validation function be a decorator. That way it gets called before the actual business logic of the function. For your example of checking whether `request.get_json()` contains the proper fields, this is how it would look like:

```py
import functools

def requires_fields(fields):
    required_fields = set(fields)

    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(decorated)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            current_fields = set(request.get_json().keys())
            missing_fields = required_fields
            if missing_fields:
                return jsonify({'error': 'missing fields', 'fields': list(missing_fields)}), 400  # Bad Request
            resp = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return resp
    return wrapper

# usage:

@app.route('/comment', methods=['POST'])
@requires_fields(['author', 'post_id', 'body'])
def create_comment():
    data = request.get_json()
    id = FoobarDB.insert('comment', author=data['author'], post_id=data['post_id'], body=data['body'])
    return jsonify({'new_id': id}), 201  # Created
```

If you must leave it the way it is now, then in order to not return data from the validation function, you must raise an `HTTPException`. The default function to do it is `flask.abort(code)`.